# Sort data based on multiple fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a requirement to sort the data and below is what my data looks like.

```
[
  {
    "id": "course1",
    "type": "course",
    "sequence": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "course2",
    "type": "course",
    "sequence": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "course1_chapter1",
    "type": "chapter",
    "sequence": 1,
    "course": {
      "id": "course1",
      "sequence": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "course1_chapter2",
    "type": "chapter",
    "sequence": 2,
    "course": {
      "id": "course1",
      "sequence": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "course2_chapter1",
    "type": "chapter",
    "sequence": 1,
    "course": {
      "id": "course1",
      "sequence": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "course1_chapter1_lesson1",
    "type": "lesson",
    "sequence": 1,
    "course": {
      "id": "course1",
      "sequence": 1
    },
    "chapter": {
      "id": "chapter1",
      "sequence": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "course1_chapter1_lesson2",
    "type": "lesson",
    "sequence": 2,
    "course": {
      "id": "course1",
      "sequence": 1
    },
    "chapter": {
      "id": "chapter1",
      "sequence": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "course1_chapter2_lesson1",
    "type": "lesson",
    "sequence": 1,
    "course": {
      "id": "course1",
      "sequence": 1
    },
    "chapter": {
      "id": "chapter1",
      "sequence": 2
    }
  }
]
```

Now my requirement is to sort the data based on type 1st where the order should be course, chapter, and lesson, and then order based on the sequence. So my final outcome expectation is as per the above data

```
course1, course2, course1_chapter1, course1_chapter2, course2_chapter1, course1_chapter1_lesson1, course1_chapter1_lesson2, course1_chapter1_lesson2, course1_chapter2_lesson1
```

The sample data which I have mentioned is already in sorted manner but in real time scenario, I get unsorted data.

right now I have sorted just by Type using the score.
I could do the sorting by splitting the data into different variable and finally get the sorted data into single variable but would like to know if there is any advance option which I might not be aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single expression in your `sort` callback:

```js
const data = [{"id": "course1","type": "course","sequence": 1},{"id": "course2","type": "course","sequence": 2},{"id": "course1_chapter1","type": "chapter","sequence": 1,"course": {"id": "course1","sequence": 1}},{"id": "course1_chapter2","type": "chapter","sequence": 2,"course": {"id": "course1","sequence": 1}},{"id": "course2_chapter1","type": "chapter","sequence": 1,"course": {"id": "course1","sequence": 2}},{"id": "course1_chapter1_lesson1","type": "lesson","sequence": 1,"course": {"id": "course1","sequence": 1},"chapter": {"id": "chapter1","sequence": 1}},{"id": "course1_chapter1_lesson2","type": "lesson","sequence": 2,"course": {"id": "course1","sequence": 1},"chapter": {"id": "chapter1","sequence": 1}},{"id": "course1_chapter2_lesson1","type": "lesson","sequence": 1,"course": {"id": "course1","sequence": 1},"chapter": {"id": "chapter1","sequence": 2}}];

const result = data.sort((a, b) =>
    !b.course - !a.course || !b.chapter - !a.chapter
    || a.course?.sequence  - b.course?.sequence 
    || a.chapter?.sequence - b.chapter?.sequence 
    || a.sequence - b.sequence
).map(a => a.id);

console.log(result);
```

The first line of the expression checks if both items have a different granularity (for example, one has a chapter, the other doesn't). If this condition is true, then precedence is given to the item that has least granularity.

If that condition is false (i.e. they have the *same* granularity), then the available sequences are compared.

Comment: My thoughts went in a different direction (like `undefined - 1`), I forgot that at that point you've already sorted out granularity. So it's either `sequence - sequence` or `undefined - undefined` where treating NaN as 0 is correct.

Comment: Thank you this worked out well. is it possible to do the same sorting in ElasticSearch Query?

Comment: Glad to hear! Not sure what you mean with *sorting* in ElasticSearch Query, but if you cannot make it work, I suggest you ask a new question focused (and tagged) on that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function takes as argument a comparison function that must return a negative value if its first argument is less than its second, a positive value if its first argument is greater than its second, and zero if they are equal.

You can use this technique in your case by comparing the significance of types (course is more significant than chapter) and by comparing the sequence numbers within a given type:

```js
const types = ["course", "chapter", "lesson"];
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.type !== b.type) return types.indexOf(a.type) - types.indexOf(b.type);
  for (var t of types) {
    if (t === a.type) return a.sequence - b.sequence;
    var d = a[t].sequence - b[t].sequence;
    if (d !== 0) return d;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback function of the [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, which specifies how to order items.

The callback returns `-1` when item `a` should be placed before `b`, and `1` when `b` should be placed before `a`.

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.type !== b.type) {
        if (a.type === "course") return -1;
        if (b.type === "course") return 1;
        if (a.type === "chapter") return -1;
        if (b.type === "chapter") return 1;
    }
    if (a.sequence > b.sequence) return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

You should be careful when using the `sort` function, because it sorts the array in-place, meaning that you will lose the original unsorted array. If you need to keep the original and the sorted version, you can create a clone of the array using a variety of methods.

Here's a snippet demonstrating the effects of this sort on your data:

```js
var array = [

    {
        "id": "course2",
        "type": "course",
        "sequence": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "course1_chapter1",
        "type": "chapter",
        "sequence": 1,
        "course": {
            "id": "course1",
            "sequence": 1
        }
    },

    {
        "id": "course1_chapter2",
        "type": "chapter",
        "sequence": 2,
        "course": {
            "id": "course1",
            "sequence": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "course1",
        "type": "course",
        "sequence": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "course1_chapter1_lesson2",
        "type": "lesson",
        "sequence": 2,
        "course": {
            "id": "course1",
            "sequence": 1
        },
        "chapter": {
            "id": "chapter1",
            "sequence": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "course2_chapter1",
        "type": "chapter",
        "sequence": 1,
        "course": {
            "id": "course1",
            "sequence": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "course1_chapter1_lesson1",
        "type": "lesson",
        "sequence": 1,
        "course": {
            "id": "course1",
            "sequence": 1
        },
        "chapter": {
            "id": "chapter1",
            "sequence": 1
        }
    },

    {
        "id": "course1_chapter2_lesson1",
        "type": "lesson",
        "sequence": 1,
        "course": {
            "id": "course1",
            "sequence": 1
        },
        "chapter": {
            "id": "chapter1",
            "sequence": 2
        }
    }
]

console.log("Original Array: ", array);

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.type !== b.type) {
        if (a.type === "course") return -1;
        if (b.type === "course") return 1;
        if (a.type === "chapter") return -1;
        if (b.type === "chapter") return 1;
    }
    if (a.sequence > b.sequence) return 1;

    return -1;
});

console.log("Ordered Array: ", array);
```

Comment: "It is *mutating* (the array)" not *mutable* (changing itself)

Comment: If both items are lessons, it will sort then by the lesson sequence, ignoring in what course or chapter they are. Like `course1_chapter1_lesson5 > course5_chapter5_lesson1` which is wrong